# OpenCV DNN Inference from ONNX file - Error

Tags: opencv, onnx

I'm trying to run an inference using the OpenCV DNN framework of an ONNX file.

The problem is that when i'm trying to run the following code:

```cpp
auto path = "path to the a RGB image...";
constexpr char TEST_DEFAULT_ONNX_FILENAME_[] = "unet_h256_w320.onnx";       
int width = 320;
int height = 256;
std::filesystem::path _model = "path to the onnx file..."
cv::Mat cpu_img = cv::imread(path);
cv::resize(cpu_img, cpu_img, cv::Size(320, 256));

cv::cvtColor(cpu_img, cpu_img, CV_BGR2RGB);
cpu_img.convertTo(cpu_img, CV_32F);
cv::Mat blob;
float scale = 1.0;
blob = cv::dnn::blobFromImage(cpu_img, scale, cv::Size(width, height), cv::Scalar(), false); 

  
int backendId = 0;
int targetId = 0;
cv::dnn::Net net = cv::dnn::readNetFromONNX(_model.string());
net.setPreferableBackend(backendId);
net.setPreferableTarget(targetId);


net.setInput(blob, "input");
net.forward(net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames();
```

I then receive the following error: *(OCR of [screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLebm.png) because commenters are impatient and DIY)*

`OpenCV(4.5.0) Error: Assertion failed (start <= (int)shape.size() && end <= (int)shape.size() && start <= end) in cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200908::total, file F:\Projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\include\opencv2/dnn/shape_utils.hpp, line 171`

Now, what's odd is that when i'm applying the inference over the opencv-python api, using almost the exact methods, i do manage to apply the inference without any troubles whatsoever - attaching the python code here:

```
opencv_net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromONNX("path to the same onnx file...")
x = np.random.randn(3,256,320).astype(np.float32)
input_blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image=x)
opencv_net.setInput(input_blob)
opencv_net.forward()
```

Also attaching the NN model here:
[very long picture of a graph, 19440 pixels tall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4iUz.jpg)

**UPDATE**
Solved -> Updating from opencv version 4.5.0 to the latest (4.5.4+) solved the issue, i don't know to point what exactly in the release notes did the trick, though it is now working

Comment: please post errors as TEXT, not as image, thank you

Comment: In the Python version, you test inference with a synthetic image, while in the C++ you use an existing image. Maybe that hints the error, are the dimensions (height, width, channels) of the image the correct ones expected by the network?

Comment: Are the opencv versions in python and c++ the same? With every version, opencv gets more compatibility features for onnx (additional layer types etc.)

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/21967

Comment: Seems like it's the opencv difference in versions that made the error - added more info in the original post

Comment: Please write the solution as an answer @NirYakobovits